# cannot get package and class name if object class is array on field using java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have some problem.

```
class example{
     Text text=new Text();
     int a;
     JLabel[] label=new JLabel[3];
     Panel[][][] panel=new Panel[5][5][5];
}
```

so, i have tried reflection :

```
Class cls=Class.forName("example");
Field[]f=cls.getDeclaredFields();
for(field : f){
     field.getType().getPackage();
     field.getType().getName();
}
```

the result of package is null and result of class like [[[Ljava.awt.Panel

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the package name, which would be javax.swing in this case?

Comment: make a list package name loaded from my code.

Comment: @newbie And what is the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array is a special type. It does not belong to any package.

Try (untested):

```
Class cls=Class.forName("example");
Field[]f=cls.getDeclaredFields();
for(Field field : f){
     Class<?> type = field.getType()
     int numArrayDimensions= 0;
     while (type.isArray()){
        type = type.getComponentType();
        numArrayDimensions++;
     }
     if (! type.isPrimitive()){
         Package pkg = type.getPackage();
     }
     String className = getFormattedClassName(type, numArrayDimensions);

}

private String getFormattedClassName(Class<?> type, int numArrayDimensions){
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(type.getName());
         IntStream.range(0, numArrayDimensions).foreach(dimension -> sb.append("[]"));
         return sb.toString();
}
```

Primitives on the other hand are a language feature. The class objects representing them do not belong to any package.

Comment: it is error, if i take primitive data type and multiple arrays.

Comment: @newbie I've updated my answer. Please have a look at the Javadoc when you're looking for fitting methods: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Comment: @newbie Can you update your question and show what is expected result?

Comment: @newbie ? I rejected the edit. How should `String type2=field.getType().getCanonicalName();` help you with getting the package? Parsing? Is there an error in my code?

Comment: @newbie Please don't refer to code at external sites. Just tell what is not working or why you think there is a better way.

Comment: i very sorry i'm get array like this : 
class [[Ljavax.swing.JPanel;

Comment: @newbie And what did you want to get?

Comment: i want the result like JLabel[] Panel[][][].

Comment: @newbie Didn't you want to get the package?

Comment: @newbie As I wrote you have to replace if with while. I've updated my answer now.

Comment: i'm sorry, yes i want get package and class.
but it's result  class [[Ljavax.swing.JPanel
so i want to split package and class like javax.swing and JPanel[][][].

Comment: so, because the package is null, my program cannot access class name.

Comment: @newbie Please edit your question with proper example of what you have and what you want since what you are saying now has very little to do with your question title and its content.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments I assume that what you want to achieve is to print type of fields in similar way they are declared in class. So if for class like

```
class Example {
    int a;
    int[][] f;
    JLabel[][] label = new JLabel[3][];
    String s;
}
```

you would like to get

```
int
int[][]
javax.swing.JLabel[][]
java.lang.String
```

then on `Field` instance representing declared field use `field.getType().getTypeName()`.

- `field.getType()` will return Class representing what type can be stored in field,
- and `getTypeName()` returns name in easy to read form, so for field `int[][] f;` you will get `int[][]` instead of `[[I`.

Demo:

```
class Example {
    int a;
    int[][] f;
    JLabel[][] label = new JLabel[3][];
    String s;
}

class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] ar) {
        Class<?> cls = Example.class;
        Field[] fields = cls.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field f : fields) {
            System.out.println(f.getType().getTypeName());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for getTypeName which was introduce in Java SE 8. I wasn't aware of this method. If the OP doesn't need the package and the name separately then this is the cleaner solution.

Comment: But then the getCanonicalName() method the OP mentioned in a comment provides the same output. So it's still unclear what the OP is asking.

Comment: `getCanonicalName` is very similar. For now main difference in output between `getTypeName` I could find is when we will print type of non-static inner class which `getCanonicalName` will print as `Outer$Inner` but `getTypeName` as `Outer.Inner` which is closer to way we write it in code.

Comment: But I agree, we still don't know if OP really wants to achieve, that is why I at start of this answer I said that it was based on OP comments (which ware also not very clear).

Answer (score -1):

Try with the following code to get the package name

```
        Package p=cls.getPackage();
        System.out.println(p.getName());
```

I have tried with sample program

```
        Class cls=Countcharacters.class;            
        Package p=cls.getPackage();
        System.out.println(p.getName());
```

and got the out as Sflow  which is my package name

Comment: The OP is asking about array types.